# Should I strictly validate email address for signing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, email-validation

We are building and running a website in Ruby on rails. For authentication we have used devise gem.

Recently we found lots of registrations happening on our website with fake email address. Attacker is not confirming account but just doing registration.

I know I can strictly validate email address for mx record and not let invalid domain or un-existing mailboxes signup. e.g. [email_verifier](https://github.com/kamilc/email_verifier)

But I have seen shopping site and content platforms, let people register with any junk email address.

I would like to know why people not implement validation when it is so simple to do it

I believe, it ensures your users table is clean and number of unconfirmed users will be less.

Comment: should belong to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is often a well known factor for developers, but a business decision has to be made. Studies that look at stats on usability vs security are often quoted showing high drop-out rates when email addresses on accounts need to be verified. A lot of e-commerce businesses would rather expose themselves to risks and workload of junk accounts than risk going against this and possibly reduce their conversion rates for sales.